# How to install Ubuntu on a CR-48 Chromebook?

Tags: installation, chromebook

A few weeks ago my chromebook got crazy and its OS got corrupted for an unknown reason.
I'd like to instal Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on it using a bootable USB pendrive, but since it is not the usual installation that I am used to on PCs/laptops....I am a bit stuck and dont even know where to start. I'd simply like to make a pendrive that I can make bootable for my chromebook and do the installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways - one requires the Chrome OS to be present and utilizes the kernel there, but you can't do it from a bootable USB stick. The other way involves flashing a new BIOS - but again, you have to be in a workable Chrome OS session. I think the BIOS flash tool got pulled by its creator and is hard to find. But either way, you will need to restore Chrome OS. There is a recovery to do this -

[Recover to stock cr48](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1080595)

Once its recovered, just google for the cr48 BIOS to install from a pen drive - good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Although this cr48 seems to be a nightmare.....I keep getting an error message with the new installation of the chrome OS. I just simply give up. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ubuntu on chromebook is a difficult task as far as I know.

It require turn on the developer option & using custom linux kernel.

Few guides are available in internet

http://liliputing.com/2012/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-on-the-199-acer-c7-chromebook.html

http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.in/2012/04/chrubuntu-1204-now-with-double-bits.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy to follow step by step guide to turn the new $249 Samsung Chromebook into a full featured netbook by installing Ubuntu Linux. Once complete you can have a dual boot Samsung Chromebook with ChromeOS one one SSD drive and Ubuntu 12 on the other SSD drive.

http://techfoobar.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-samsungs-new.html"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have installed Ubuntu on a Chromebook is by using Crouton.

1. Enter developer mode.
2. At the scary boot screen press Ctrl+D
3. It will take a while to start up. Enter your Google information.
4. Click on this download link: https://goo.gl/fd3zc and save the file to your Downloads folder. In case this link has become obsolete, you can find the latest link to the same file at this webpage: [GitHub dnschneid/crouton - Chromium OS Universal Chroot Environment](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/).
5. Press the keyboard combination Ctrl+Alt+T
6. Type `shell` and hit Enter.
7. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t unity
   ```